# Symfony form - choiceType from class attributes

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I have a class Options with many attributes, nested in B class

```
class Options {    
    private $foo;
    private $bar;    
    // getter setters ..
}

class B {
    private $baz;
    private $options; // Option class
}
```

Is there a way to make a ChoiceType with checkboxes from B.options attributes ?

```
$options = new Options();
$b = new B();
$b->setOptions($options);

$form = $this->createForm(MyType::class, $b, []);

// ...

$builder->add('options', ??,[
        // ??
    ];
```

What are the best practices for that kind of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to [embed a collection of forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html). Symfony links entities in forms very well. Check the link for documentation.

Comment: (It is not an Entity but a common class in other common class.) And it will not put every attributes in a checkbox list...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ChoiceType`. If `expanded` and `multiple` options is set to `true`, checkboxes will be rendered.

```
$builder->add('options', ChoiceType::class, [
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
]);
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#expanded